# REST standards for posting data

Tags: api, http, rest, ember.js, servicestack

I am using Ember.

The model being posted by ember is

```
{
    "user": {
        "firstName": "Vivek",
        "lastName": "Muthal"
    }
}
```

Ember had wrapped the data into `"user"` object.
But the service I have written accepts only `{"firstName":"string","lastName":"string"}`.

So my question is does REST standards specifies to send / receive data in wrapped Object only?
Any references please so I can change the service accordingly.
Or else I will modify the ember to use my current service as it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the resource is `User`, so the JSON should represent a `User`. Lets say you have this `URI` schema.

```
GET /host/users/{userId}
PUT /host/users/{userId}
POST /host/users
```

When we do `GET` we expect a `JSON` that represents A `User`

```
{
    "firstName": "Vivek",
    "lastName": "Muthal"
}
```

There is no need to specify the resource name because we already mentioned that in our `GET` request, The same for `POST`, there is no need to mention the resource name in the request body because it is specified in the request `URI`.So no there, is no need for `user` key.

Comment: right, so let say GET /host/users then ember wants the response array in "users" object. I just want more clarification or any references to confirm it. Don't understand why ember forces this convention.

Comment: @VivekMuthal I dont know why ember forces this convention, the right way to identify a resource in REST is by its URI. Your JSON represents a resource identified by a URI.

Comment: Thanks for information. Found solution in ember. They provide a RESTSerializer where just have to add serializeIntoHash: function (hash, type, record, options) { Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(record, options)); }

Answer (score 0):

REST defines an [uniform interface constraint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5). This constraint states that you have to use standards solutions to create an uniform interface between the service and the clients. This way the clients will be decoupled by the implementation details of the service, because the standards we use are not maintained by the server...

To make it short you can use any standard MIME type, or define a vendor specific MIME type. I strongly suggest you to use an existing hypermedia format like JSON-LD+Hydra or HAL. I guess this kind of serialization is an ember specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no predefined format for the data you send in the body of your HTTP requests. Well ok, the HTTP RFCs do put technical limits on the data you send, but the formatting is entirely up to you.

As such, you can format your data however you want. You just need to represent the resource. You do need to consider if the JSON for a user should clearly mark the object as a 'user' or not, I would consider it mostly redundant to do so.